# typecast to int in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to query a table which a json column

```
select * 
from subscription 
where extras->>'end_date' > 1592424632;
```

this errors out saying

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "end_date"

I have tried type casting

```
select * 
from subscription 
where extras->>'end_date'::int4 > 1592424632;
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "end_date"

and extras column sample input looks like

```
{"end_date": 1592425146, "capacity": 1, "start_date": 1584562746, "devices": "", "quantity": 10}
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good catch! Learning every day :-). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses. The cast operator `::` has a higher precedence than the `->` operator. So `extras->>'end_date'::int4` is parsed as `extras->> ('end_date'::int4)` which is the reason for the error.

```
select * 
from subscription 
where (extras->>'end_date')::int4 > 1592424632
```